# Accessing Python List

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models

Hi I have this list which is working for what initially intended for

```
gp_list_t = [int(i) for i in gp_list]
gp_lits3 = gp_list_t[0]
agencys_sp = GPSpecial.objects.filter(agencys=user_agency,is_active=True,id =gp_lits3).values_list('agencys')
```

Now say they are more than `1` values on the list -gp_list_t. How do I access other values on the list that i want to use on my variable agencys_sp

Updated Code :

```
gp_list_t = [int(i) for i in gp_list]
agencys_sp=GPSpecial.objects.filter(agencys=user_agency,is_active=True,id=gp_list_t).values_list('agencys')
for value, in agencys_sp:
                            agency_tu = [i for i, in agencys_sp]
```

returns error int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'list'

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `in` filter operator to query all rows matching the IDs in the `gp_list_t`. Then iterate over the queryset with a `for` loop:

```
gp_list_t = [int(i) for i in gp_list]
agencys_sp = GPSpecial.objects.filter(agencys=user_agency,is_active=True,id__in=gp_list_t).values_list('agencys')
for value, in agencys_sp:
    print(value)
```

Comment: the code is only getting the first element gp_lits3 = gp_list_t[0] if there are more elements or values how do i make sure it get other values

Comment: i need to put those values from agencys_ sp into a list as well : agency_tu = [i[0] for i in agencys_sp]

Comment: Yes, that's how you can do it.

Comment: Alternatively, you can use `[i for i, in agencys_sp]` to extract the values in the tuples.

Comment: can you check my updated code it is returning an error : int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'list' but when use my original code it works the only thing it use the first element but if there are other element in the list gp_list_t then it will not use it

Comment: You shouldn't put it in a loop. The loop in my code is just for printing. If you want to make it a list, remove the `for` loop and simply do `agency_tu = [i for i, in agencys_sp]`.

Comment: i have done that still error comes up if i use this gp_list_t = [int(i) for i in gp_list]
                            gp_lits3 = gp_list_t[0]
                            agencys_sp = GPSpecial.objects.filter(agencys=user_agency,is_active=True,id = gp_lits3).values_list('agencys') it works .. only the first elemnt is use

Comment: this line gp_list_t = [int(i) for i in gp_list] return this elemnent [902, 900] but i also i want to use the second one as well if id 902 does not include agency for that user